# Ruby on Rails Association -> User - Timesheet - Employee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

I'm trying to build a relationship between models following the guidelines:

A user has many employees
Employee belongs to a user

User has many timesheets
Timesheet belongs to a user

Timesheet has many employees
Employees are part of many timesheets

The timesheet should record all the employees related to user and how many hours they worked for that specific timesheet.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: could you tell us what you tried so far?

Comment: Good luck with it and keep us posted!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. It sounds like you are already have the relations. What have you tried thus far in rails to create the model you're attempting?

Comment: i'm ok creating the user -> employee,  user -> timesheet relationships... but my problem is creating the Timesheet -> Employee relationship. I have the timesheet has many employees.. but what should i do for the Employee model? Employee is part of many timesheets.. how would I go about creating that?

Answer (score 0):

Employee has and belongs to many timesheets

Time sheets has and belongs to many employees.

```
User.first.timesheets.first.employees
```

From the sound of it this is what you're after?

Comment: Thanks... I solved the problem by using a has_many :through relationship.